# How to trigger a browser window or tab close event with jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to trigger a window/tab close event with jQuery. I already tried with

```
$('selector').unload()
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: version deprecated: 1.8

Comment: Please see here for your problem solution. May it will help you. Thank You
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser

Answer (score 10):

You can use [`unload()`](http://api.jquery.com/unload/) on the `window` property in jQuery:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
   //do stuff
});
```

You don't *need* jQuery to do it though, you can use good ol' fashioned JavaScript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e){
    var msg = 'Are you sure?';
    e = e || window.event;

    if(e)
        e.returnValue = msg;

    return msg;
}
```

Comment: java script method worked. thanks but I need something like this $(window).unload(function() {
   window.location='clearsession.php'
}); How can I do it with js

Comment: It will also called when user navigate to some other page rather than closing the window

Answer (score 1):

**In Javascript**

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    var message = 'Important: Please click on \'Save\' button to leave this page.';
    if (typeof event == 'undefined') {
        event = window.event;
    }
    if (event) {
        event.returnValue = message;
    }
    return message;
};
```

**In jQuery**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Comment: It works including page refresh, I need specifically for tab close or browser close

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(window).unload(function() {  
        alert("Unload");  
});​
```

**Note :** some times dialogs are blocked in unload . You can check your console to make it confirm.

Comment: What if person is not closing browser but navigating to some other page. unload will also run in that condition.